# Building an embedded system

Tags: usb, wifi, microcontroller, rtos

I want to build an embedded system with USB and Wifi. I am going to use USB to load configuration and code. Wifi will be used to communicate with other similar systems. I would also like to program at the socket level, which means I want the drivers for USB and Wifi already available and an OS. So if someone can point me to a set of things I might need to bootstrap such a system, it would be very helpful. Or an existing system with an RTOS that can be used would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/about.html) is a true RTOS with support for USB and TCP/IP.

One problem you may have with any RTOS is getting device driver support for any particular WiFi device. It may be simpler to use a [WiFi Module](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/wifi) that connects to your embedded system via a SPI or UART interface or similar and has the complete stack on-board.

Similarly you can get [USB-serial chips](http://www.ftdichip.com/) that avoid the complexities and processor load of implementing USB on your application processor.  Not least it avoids the need for a USB vendor ID which will cost you $2000.

If you use stand-alone WiFi and USB modules your choice of RTOS becomes much broader since you avoid the need for so much middleware and a simple RTOS kernel providing threading, timing and IPC may suffice.

Of course a Linux based solution may suit, but the key issues with that is that Linux is not an RTOS, and it requires large memory resources.

WinCE/Windows Embedded Compact is another option, but is again relatively large and the licensing cost may be prohibitive.  It is to an extent real-time capable in the sense that it is deterministic is not particularly fast.

.Net Micro might be an option, but is not real-time and while requiring fewer resources that either Linux or Windows Embedded Compact, it remains relatively large.

[QNX Neutrino](http://www.qnx.com/products/neutrino-rtos/neutrino-rtos.html#overview) is probably the one solution with the scalability, real-time capability and middleware and hardware support you need, but there the licensing costs may again be prohibitive.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page). it enables you to customize and build your own embedded linux distribution. And there are distributions already built with OE such as the [Ångström Distribution](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) which I have had success using.

Comment: CONFIG_RT adds some real-time features to the Linux scheduler - that does not make it an RTOS by any means.  See [Seven real-time approaches to Linux](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Seven-realtime-Linux-approaches-Part-C/).  Admittedly this is an very old article, and things may have changed, but therein lies the issue - how do you know it will truly meet deadlines in all instances?  The Wiki is a bit light on performance figures, such as context switch times, determinism and interrupt latencies.  Use with care, and it is still *huge* and difficult to scale.

Comment: Things have changed a lot, getting rid of the big kernel lock has made the RT patches pretty real time. My background is from vxworks, and I too once scoffed at the idea of real time linux, but now I am working with real time linux in the 3.6 kernel and in fact it achieves our real time requirements.

Comment: As ever with real-time - there's a spectrum, and if Linux RT meets requirements in a particular case then of course it should be considered, and I can see how it would be attractive after Wind River's VxWorks licensing and support costs!  It is compelling perhaps if hardware support and connectivity are primary factors and the target has sufficient memory resources.  Targets without an MMU however cannot benefit from the inherent robustness of a memory protected user environment.